# Compare dates in 2 dataframes when using pandas update

Tags: python, pandas

In this case I've been trying to update one dataframe with another using

`df.update(other)`

My dataframes look like the following

```
df1
       
     | Date       |  Note    | PC    | T |
     |------------|----------|-------|---|
   0 | 10/1/2021  | Complete | 8017  | 2 |
   1 | 9/28/2021  | Pending  | 5019  | 2 |
   2 | 9/7/2021   | Canceled | 8015  | 1 |
   3 | 4/21/2021  | Complete | 8870  | 1 |
   4 | 1/1/2020   | Pending  | 8305  | 3 |


df2
     | Date       |  Note    | PC    | T |
     |------------|----------|-------|---|
   0 | 10/20/2021 | Pending  | 8017  | 2 |
   1 | 9/14/2021  | Complete | 5019  | 2 |
   2 | 9/3/2021   | Canceled | 8015  | 1 |
```

And I want to do `df1.update(df2)` but only if `df2['Date'] > df1['Date']`

So first what I do is:

```
df1.set_index('PC', drop=False, inplace=True)
df2.set_index('PC', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

So I can update on the correct index but when I try to compare the dates, I'm at a lost.

My expected outcome would be something like this:

```
df1
       
     | Date       |  Note    | PC    | T |
     |------------|----------|-------|---|
8017 | 10/20/2021 | Pending  | 8017  | 2 |
5019 | 9/28/2021  | Pending  | 5019  | 2 |
8015 | 9/7/2021   | Canceled | 8015  | 1 |
8870 | 4/21/2021  | Complete | 8870  | 1 |
8305 | 1/1/2020   | Pending  | 8305  | 3 |
```

I've read in the `update` documentation and I found `filter_func`

> filter_func callable(1d-array) -> bool 1d-array, optional
> Can choose to replace values other than NA. Return True for values that should be updated.

But when I try something like

`df1.update(df2, filter_func = df2['Date] > df1['Date'])`

It doesn't work.

It seems like the `filter_func` is the way to go but I can't seem to find a proper way to make it work with the function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @not_speshal Correct. Updating the row for each "PC" with the latest date. I will make an edit with the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
greater_date = lambda row1,row2: row1 if row1['Date'] > row2['Date'] else row2
df1.combine(df2, greater_date)
```

Comment: Assigning a name to a lambda function is usually considered bad practice. You're making an anonymous function.... non-anonymous.

Comment: @Z4-tier I don't disagree, assigning a lambda function a name is bad practice.  I likely should have linked https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html (which, perhaps for the sake of showing the example with several different options, does assign a name to a lambda function)